# Given DDL for a postgres DB, how can I recreate that schema and data in Salesforce.com?

Tags: salesforce

I have a Salesforce developer account and need to recreate a schema and data that I have in postgres. I would think there would be a way to execute DDL against Salesforce, but that does not seem to be the case. The documentation is all over the place. I have created an "object" and thought I could use data loader or something else to source it, but I have not had any success.

Any suggestions?

Comment: While I didn't find a way to load DDL, I was able to accomplish my data load from postgres using the following steps: 

1. Use schema builder to model your tables as custom objects. (https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=schema_builder_elements_objects_ref.htm&language=en_US) 
2. Export your data from postgres and save as csv files (add headers for easier importing in the next step). 
3. Use the data import wizard to load your csv and map elements to columns from postgres. (https://na30.salesforce.com/ui/setup/dataimporter)

Comment: Link to data importer help: https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=data_import_wizard.htm